Reflection and refraction in one dimension. Explicit formula seems to contradict the literature?
I tried to derive the formulae for a 1D reflected/refracted wave given an incident wave $\phi_0(x,t)$ and my answer seems to contradict the answers found in certain websites. I wonder why there is the inconsistency?
Suppose that the speed of a wave (e.g. light) is $c_1$ for $x<0$ and $c_2$ for $x\geq 0$. I want to find a the formula for the reflected and refracted wave in terms of the incident wave. Let $\phi_0(x,t)$ be the incident wave, thus $$c_1^2\partial_{x}^2 \phi_0(x,t) - \partial_t ^2 \phi_0(x,t) = 0$$ holds for all $x,t \in \mathbb{R}$. That is, $\phi_0$ is a solution if the wave speed were $c_1$ on all of $\mathbb{R}$. If it helps, let us just consider the case where $\phi(x,0) = 0$ for $x>0$ (the wave is arriving from the left and is initially zero on the right of $x=0$).
Now, we let the reflected wave will be of the form $$\alpha \phi_0(-x,t)$$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and the refracted wave will be of the form $$\beta \phi_0(\gamma x, t)$$ for some $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ where $$\gamma = \frac{c_1}{c_2}.$$ Thus our total wave is $$\phi_1(x,t) = \phi_0(x,t) + \alpha \phi_0(-x,t) \quad \text{for } x \leq 0$$ and  $$\phi_2(x,t) = \beta \phi_0(\gamma x,t) \quad \text{for } x \geq 0.$$
We now impose the natural interface conditions $$\phi_1(0,t) = \phi_2(0,t)$$ and $$c_1^2\partial_x \phi_1(0,t) = c_2^2\partial_x \phi_2(0,t).$$
These two equations translate to $$1+\alpha = \beta $$ and $$\gamma (1-\alpha) = \beta$$ where we recall that $\gamma = c_1/c_2$.
The gives $$\alpha = \frac{\gamma - 1}{\gamma + 1}$$ and $$\beta = \frac{2\gamma}{1+\gamma}.$$ In particular, this means that if $c_1 > c_2$, i.e., $\gamma > 1$, i.e., the wave is faster on the left side, then we have $\alpha > 0 $ and $\beta > 1$ and thus the refracted wave has a larger height (amplitude) than the incident wave. This seems to contradict the animation at the bottom of this webpage which suggests the opposite inequalities should hold: https://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/demos/reflect/reflect.html
https://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/Demos/reflect/lo-hi.gif
My question is where I have gone wrong or is this webpage wrong?

You actually have not stated your problem in sufficient detail for an actual answer to exist.
However, if the system in question is two strings of different mass densities joined together, then the appropriate boundary condition is stated to be "same tension across the junction" as
$$\partial_x\phi_1(0,t)=\partial_x\phi_2(0,t)$$
as opposed to what you have. Again, without greater specification, we cannot know if there is a mistake anywhere. You should fix that.

I see, if I use that boundary condition instead then its probably consistent with the source. I was initially motivated from electromagnetic waves, and thought that this 1D example would be the same. So perhaps different areas of physics involving waves (e.g., strings with densities versus light travelling from air to glass) have different boundary conditions.
